# How to walk through two identically shaped dataframes cell by cell and apply some logic by cell comparison

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to compare two identically shaped dataframes cell by cell applying some function depending on the comparison result.
some psydocode for illustration

```py
for cell in dataframes:
  if cells are equal:
    do someting
  else:
    do someting else
```

I checked the [DataFrame.compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) method but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: post a testable dataframe fragments and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question clearly, this could help:

```
for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df1.shape[1]):
        if df1.iloc[i, j] == df2.iloc[i, j]:
            # Do something
            pass
        else:
            # Do something else
            pass
```

Comment: The classic for loop... it works. Thanks.